# How to render props conditionally and checking for undefined, while passing props via React useHistory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I have component1 where I am redirecting user to other page and passing props like this

```
onClick={() =>history.push({pathname: "/student/planandprice", state: {plan: history.plan.courseName, as:history.availableSession}})}>Upgrade</Button>
```

So I want to render it on component2 only when its not undefined, its not undefined when i navigate from component1 to component2 via onclick because history.push(useHistory) method is executed. But I navigate directly to component 2, I get undefined error. I tried to check undefined values using condition:
`{props? props.location.state.as : ""}`
but its still not working and gives "Cannot read property 'as' of undefined" so how to check undefined values and render it conditionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
{props ? props?.location?.state?.as : ""}
```

Comment: This solution worked, however can you explain me the basic logic behind it in simple words? I can check docs but its looking bit daunting and overloaded with info

Comment: Certainly. Basically, it checks if the key before the question mark is defined/exists before moving to the next key. If it doesn't exist, is stops checking & whole expression reads 'false-y', basically. Does that help?